# HiveAccessControlException Permission Denied: user does not have [ALL] privilege

Tags: hive, hdfs, apache-ranger

I am very new to hive and the hadoop ecosystem.

I am trying to create a new table in hive but I am encountering this error:

[image]

According to some suggestions, I have to set the Ranger policies but upon checking, policies already had permissions to "All"

[image]

Same permissions were also given to other policies.

[image]

Did I miss something? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You might need HDFS user directory which can be created by the administrator using `sudo -u hdfs hdfs dfs -mkdir /user/<user_id>`

In case you want to check if there is one exists:

```
hdfs dfs -ls /user | grep <user_id>
```

Comment: Though it is good to do this step, but it does not help in solving the access error

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue.  You may want to check Ranger > Audit > Plugin Status to see if the policy is being applied.  If it's not it may be that you have a jersey-client classpath conflict.  More details here:
https://jonmorisissqlblog.blogspot.com/2021/06/ranger-hive-policy-activation-time.html